# @types/express-session doesn't work. Any idea why?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings, express-session

I'm using typescript for the backend of my web-app and I have incorporated express-session. I have @types/express and @types/express-session but unfortunately I continuously get type errors stating:

- `Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'`

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Versions:

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"@types/express": "^4.17.11",
"@types/express-session": "1.17.0",
```

example code:

```js
const auth_data: authSuccess|authError = await discordClient.exchangeCodeForTokens(String(disCode));
if(!auth_data) {throw new Error('Could not Authorize!')}
req.session.oauth = auth_data;
```

The last line here would throw the type error: `Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'`

Comment: Show the code which throws this error

Comment: Ex.

'req.session.oauth = auth_data;'
would return the ts type error

Comment: The code give me: `Property 'oauth' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.ts(2339)` error. Can't reproduce the error. You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I imported express session like this:

- `const session = require('express-session')`

Instead of like this:

- `import session from 'express-session';`

Which makes total sense. I don't know why I didn't think to look at my imports!